# Commas/clauses within Haiku phrases?

Tags: poetry, haiku

I am experimenting with Haiku.

My sentiment is *"I used to count the minutes until we next met, now I count the days since you left"*.

I first looked at something like:

*Glad minutes until

Our eyes lock again, are now

Desolate days since*

"Desolate" is a deliberate *kigo* but I'm not sure if adding a clause like ", are now" really fits the form, or can be considered a *kireji* since it does form a switch of focus.

I'm sure there's plenty else wrong with it, but is splitting a phrase into 2-sub-phrases common?